# TPM 2.0 Hardware software issue?

Tags: tpm

I recently bought a  Dell Precision 5530 form a guy that I have later found out is/was a gov employee.

After changing the Nvme 50 0GB hard drive to a Samsung Evo 970 1 TB and installing Ubuntu (and setting everything correct i.e: boot to Legacy and ROM, secure boot off and sda1 to boot), the BIOS wouldn't recognize and display the new 1TB Evo 970 after selecting the Legacy option and after a reboot and the DELL logo loads the system would get stuck displaying the message:

> No bootable devices found.
>   Press F1 key to retry boot.
>   Press F2 key for setup utility.
>   Press F5 key to run onboard diagnostics.

I disabled the TPM 2.0 from the BIOS but not from within the Windows 10 500 GB Nvme drive.
Does the system have some kind of lock-down after changing hardware and/or software?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why exactly did you enable Legacy Mode?  Windows 10 fully supported UEFI mode.  Any event your current error is due to enabling Legacy Mode.  There is absolutely NOT a lockdown, unless a UEFI/BIOS password exists, which is not the case because you made firmware changes to the system.

Comment: I enabled legacy mode in order to boot from a usb and install Ubuntu. there is no BIOS password. The BIOS doesn't even show the new Evo 970 1TB, how come?

Comment: Ubuntu supports UEFI mode.  In order to use your SSD you must enable UEFI mode.

Comment: In the BIOS settings, boot sequence is set to UEFI, so should I see the Evo 970 1TB? it's not showing it, do I need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand.  You have two screenshots, one where UEFI is disabled, the other with it enabled.  If you are dual booting, and Windows was installed in UEFI mode, then you have to keep it enabled.  However, you have to use whatever mode you had enabled, while you installed Ubuntu.  Which is the reason I asked why you disabled it.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu using Legacy mode and when the system reboot for the first time it got stuck displaying the attached message, so I pressed F2 for BIOS settings -> Legacy and didn't see M.2 Nvme Evo 1TB (2nd pic). I can reinstall Ubuntu under UEFI, but both options won't recognize or display the Nvme 1TB? not sure why. I also disabled the TPM 2.0, i'm not an expert and probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Why did you disable TPM?  The only reason you would have done that is if you had BitLocker enabled.  So do you have BitLocker enabled?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I was able to install Ubuntu under UEFI secure boot and it's working fine, but I think I'll reinstall it again with a LVM on LUKS scheme, do I need to add the LUKS keys to the TPM? Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset the TPM in Ubuntu you an run this shell command:

```
sudo tpm_clear -f
```

For TPM 2.0 chips you will need https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss

```
tpm2_takeownership -c
```

Or you might have an option to clear the TPM in the BIOS.

Your issue sounds more like your boot options are wrong. I would not use legacy boot. You can boot to GRUB using UEFI. So enable UEFI boot and ensure it's got an entry for GRUB. If it doesn't you may have to repair your GRUB.

Be sure to transfer ownership in the Dell records in order to get support:

https://www.dell.com/support/assets-transfer/us/en/19#/Identify

Comment: tpm_clear is only for TPM 1.x; the second version has a completely different toolset.

Comment: And unfortunately tpm2_clear doesn't have any replacement for the -f option even in the just-released version 4.0.  I kinda agree on boot options, I really doubt every NVME drive is going to work in legacy BIOS mode. Ubuntu shouldn't need legacy anyway, last I checked it writes grub to the fallback path on the ESP so it should just work.

Comment: How should I set the BIOS? please see the attached pictures. In the BIOS settings, I set the boot sequence to UEFI, so should I see the Evo 970 1TB?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear a TPM 2.0 TPM from software there's a [Physical Presence Interface](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/Physical-Presence-Interface_1-30_0-52.pdf) standard from the TCG provided by the kernel through sysfs.  You send a request to it and reboot and the "BIOS" will prompt if you want to clear the TPM or not.  This way you can prove physical control of the system.  Otherwise the usual approach is to perform the TPM clear in the UEFI menu.

```
cd /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/ppi
cat tcg_operations
    0 4: User not required
    1 4: User not required
    2 4: User not required
    3 4: User not required
    4 4: User not required
    5 3: User required
    6 4: User not required
    7 4: User not required
    8 4: User not required
    9 4: User not required
    10 4: User not required
    11 4: User not required
    14 3: User required
    15 4: User not required
    16 4: User not required
    17 4: User not required
    18 3: User required
    21 3: User required
    22 3: User required
printf 5 > request
cat response
reboot
```